# how not to exit the console when entering data pressing Enter in Visual Basic

Tags: console

This is the code. What I basically want is the user to type a number, press Enter  and read the number in order to use it. I don't know if the console exits because of pressing the Enter button or because of other reason

```
Sub CompruebaNumeroPrimo()
        Console.Write("Función que comprueba si un nº es primo, introduce el nº")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Dim NumeroAComprobar As Integer = CType(Console.ReadLine(), Integer) 
        Dim RestosCero As Integer = 0
        For Indice As Integer = 1 To NumeroAComprobar
            If (NumeroAComprobar Mod Indice = 0) Then
                RestosCero += 1
            End If
        Next Indice
        If (RestosCero > 2) Then
            Console.Write("No es primo")
        Else
            Console.Write("Es primo")
        End If
        Console.WriteLine()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `console.read()` at the end. with the message `press any key to exit` . this will stop console from exiting.